# Translation of "Links: Miss AuberginehaarPlusZombiehasentasche."

Tags: translation, german-to-english

I cannot figure out what's meant by the following sentence:

[image]

Links means left.

I failed to find "Miss" as a German word to make sense in that context:
[Miss](http://www.dict.cc/?s=miss)

And about that long word (train), my mind recognizes "Haar", "Plus", "Zombie", "Hosentasche". So only "Aubergine" remains which must be a word too. dict suggest [eggplant](http://www.dict.cc/?s=aubergine).

Putting them altogether, we get:

> eggplanthairpluszombiepantspocket

Which makes perfect sense!

What does it mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you've read that somewhere like this, probably with a picture nearby.

My best guess would be the following:

> Links:

Is used to tell you which picture is meant.
Often if there are several pictures on one page (for example in a magazin), the captions to the pictures will be in one place using "links, rechts, oben, unten" or a combination of those to tell which is the corresponding picture.

> Miss

Probably refers to the common title of a beauty-queen.

> AuberginehaarPlusZombiehasentasche

Seems to be a noun–noun compound consisting of the following:

> Abuergine - eggplant
>
> haar - hair
>
> plus - plus or in this case with
>
> Zombie-hasen-tasche - Zombie-rabbit-bag

So probably it is meant in a quite mean and sarcastic way, to describe an so beautiful person with weird hair and a curious bag.

Well thats what I would guess from the information given.

---

After using Google a bit I'm not very sure about the last part any more.

Aubergine could be in respect to the form of the hairs. It looks a bit like sliced aubergines.

But I can't find anything in that picture that would match a zombiehasentasche.

---

**Edit:** after Using Google some more, I know it is a reference to another blog entry of that site about a Women with red to aubergine-colored hair and a bag that had a zombie-rabbit printed on it, or something like that.

---

Em1: Ich bin mal so frei und füge das Foto hinzu ;)

[image]

> Zombie-Köpfe von Adam Parker Smith. Darf ich vorstellen? Links: Miss AuberginehaarPlusZombiehasentasche. Rechts: icke, Montagmorgen. Dabei kennt der Typ mich doch gar nicht. [LINK](http://archive.crackajack.de/?p=7669)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Lukas. I added a screenshot of the page to my question. It's a translation exercise and there's nothing else as "more context". I think it is what you said.

Comment: I couldn't find anything by Googling! Wonder how you Google it, probably with you super extra German skills.

Comment: Very nice pictures @Em1! I wonder if I'll fall asleep tonight!

Comment: They doesn't seems to be zombie but they seems to be funny..They are not scary..But still I like creativity..I enjoyed the post very much..It is something new and different..

Answer (score 4):

That strange word seems to be the result of some blog posts, written by a guy with an obvious predilection for zombies:

- It seems to start [here](http://archive.crackajack.de/?p=7108), describing a female redhead with a bag that shows a skull.
- Next is [this one](http://archive.crackajack.de/?p=7526) - the author has to correct himself - it's not a skull but a "zombie rabbit" (no idea what this should be, pics would be very useful here...), and the girl's hair isn't red but of eggplant color.
- Now, the [final step](http://archive.crackajack.de/?p=7669): a picture of a puppet the resembles the author of - yesss - a girl with aubergine-coloured hair and a bag showing a zombie rabbit - in short: miss eggplanthairPLUSZombierabbit-bag.

So, Lukas was completely right with [his translation](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/4784/392), but i thought it may be useful to add some context information...

*EDIT: oh, sorry, some minutes too late - maybe nevertheless useful because of the links...*

Comment: Extremely useful. I accepted Lukas' answer since he seemed to put effort into it and I needed to know the answer very soon.